# Is this enough for a function to be increasing?

Tags: functions

Let $f, g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If $g$ is strictly increasing and $f(x) \ge g(x) $, is $f$ increasing? I believe it is, but I can't prove or disprove this.
Note : This is something I came up with while solving a problem, so feel free to adjust the constraints if the result is not true.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not. Counterexample: $g(x)=e^{x}, \; f(x)=e^{x}+\cos(x)+2$. You can convince yourself that for large negative $x,$ $f$ is not increasing.

Comment: Thank you! What if we take $f:\mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: You can modify my counterexample to match that scenario as well. The fundamental problem here is that there is simply way too much space above $g(x)$ to guarantee that $f$ is also increasing. There's too much "room for manouver".

Comment: Still no, take any bounded increasing function like $\arctan(x)$ and $\sin(x) +C$

Comment: Thank you, guys! I really appreciate your help, I am really bad at finding examples/counterexamples.

Comment: Now, you might be able to modify your constraints, and, say, add something like bounds on the difference between the derivatives. It would have to be a fairly clever constraint, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think an intuitively good pair of functions would be
$$
\begin{align*}
g(x) &= -e^{-x}\\
f(x) &= e^{-x}
\end{align*}
$$
Then $g$ is strictly increasing, and $f$ is strictly decreasing over all of $\mathbb R$; this is possible because the ranges of $f, g$ do not intersect at all.

In fact, you could ask for $f$ to have almost any kind of property, as long as it takes values only within non-negative numbers.